# How to format columns using iText7

Tags: c#, visual-studio, pdf, itext7

I'm writing a program that will allow me to print sales tags in my Bowling Pro Shop. Currently I am doing them manually but I'm looking to make it easier to create. I have created a program with VS2015 that asks for all the fields and saves it to an Access Database, and also prints it to the template I have created. The problem I am running into is formatting the text to appear as it does when I made it in Photoshop. Even if its off just a little bit that is fine but currently I cant figure out how to write it on the template the way I want.[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g5vvi.png) is the template I'm trying to print to, the bottom are formatted using Photoshop and the top is a blank one. 
Im thinking it may be easiest to create one image and add it to the pdf(5 Times).

Here is my code:

```
    private void print()
    {
        string dest = @"C:\Users\bwilliams\Desktop\balltest1.pdf";
        string src = @"C:\Users\bwilliams\Desktop\BallTags.pdf";
        Rectangle[] columns = new Rectangle[]
        {
            new Rectangle(100,500,150,200),
            new Rectangle(250,500,150,200),
            new Rectangle(400,500,150,200),
            new Rectangle(550,500,150,200)

        };
        PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(dest);
        PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(src), writer);
        Document doc = new Document(pdf,PageSize.A4.Rotate());               
        doc.SetRenderer(new ColumnDocumentRenderer(doc, columns));          
        doc.Add(new Paragraph("Ebonite").SetPaddings(150, 60, 0, 0).SetFontSize(24).SetFont(Arial).SetFixedLeading(24));
        doc.Add(new Paragraph("GB2 MVP").SetPaddings(150, 0, 0, 0).SetFontSize(24).SetFixedLeading(24));
        doc.Add(new Paragraph("$114.95").SetPaddings(150, 0, 0, 0).SetFontSize(24).SetFixedLeading(24));
        doc.Add(new Paragraph("").SetPaddings(0, 0, 0, 0).SetFontSize(24));
        doc.Add(new Paragraph("").SetPaddings(0, 0, 0, 0).SetFontSize(24));
        doc.Add(new Paragraph("").SetPaddings(0, 0, 0, 0).SetFontSize(24));
        doc.Add(new Paragraph("").SetPaddings(0, 0, 0, 0).SetFontSize(24));
        doc.Add(new Paragraph("").SetPaddings(0, 0, 0, 0).SetFontSize(24));
        doc.Add(new Paragraph("").SetPaddings(0, 0, 0, 0).SetFontSize(24));
        doc.Add(new Paragraph("").SetPaddings(0, 0, 0, 0).SetFontSize(24));







        doc.Close();
    }
```

I just have the info hard coded for now instead of using the input from text boxes.. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gxlxn.png) is what you get when you click print.

Im not sure how to format the next line over for CORE: COVER: FINISH: RG: DIFF:

I also am not sure how to add the font Arial (Black) to iText7 Font Factory.

Thanks,
Brandon

Answer (score 1):

Your post contains different questions.

**Fonts:**

You want to create a `PdfFont` in iText 7. This is done in a very different (and much easier) way when compared to iText 5. In iText 5, you had a `Font` class and a `BaseFont` class. Those are no longer necessary. You just do this:

```
PdfFont font = PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(pathToArialBlack, true);
```

In this line, `pathToArialBlack` is a path to `ARIBLK.TTF`, e.g. `C:\WINDOWS\Fonts\ARIBLK.TTF`.

**Columns:**

The question about columns is wrong. Looking at the desired result. I can't imagine why you'd use `ColumnDocumentRenderer`. I would create a `Canvas` object for every rectangle, and pass that `Canvas` object to a method that adds the content to the canvas. Make sure you add the image bytes only once by passing the `Image` object to the method rather than creating the `Image` in the method as many times as you have `Canvas` objects.

Comment: How do you add text to canvas if you arent looking to create a List?

Comment: Can you elaborate on that question? Why are you talking about a `List`? Why do you think a `List` is required? Your question sounds very strange.

Comment: The reason for my question is because the only example I found on your site is one that uses an IList in the Star Wars Example.

In your original response are you recommending that I create a canvas for each Text Box that I want to have? 

E.g. Ebonite has its own Canvas, Gamebreaker 2 has its own canvas, etc..

Comment: I was referring to the chapter that discusses Canvas: http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-building-blocks/chapter-2-working-rootelement I don't know what Ebonite and Gamebreaker 2 are about.

Comment: Is there a way to change the vertical alignment inside the canvas rectangle to "Middle" so that the text begins writing in the absolute center of the canvas rectangle?

Comment: Hi @Bruno, The link is dead now and the question about vertical alignment is interesting.. Can you update a little? TIA..